# Passing a C++ array to Ada95

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, ada

I'm trying to pass an array of unsigned integers from C++ to Ada. The Ada Lovelace tutorial states that an Ada array corresponds to a pointer to the first element of an array in C++.

Here is what I'm trying to do.

C++

```
unsigned int buffer[bufferSize];

...

unsigned int* getBuffer() {
    return buffer;
}
```

Ada

```
pragma Import (C, C_Get_Buffer, "getBuffer");

...

function C_Get_Buffer returns System.Address;

...

Buffer : array (1 .. Buffer_Size) of Interfaces.C.Unsigned;

...

Buffer'Address := C_Get_Buffer;
```

I'm finding that Buffer'Address cannot be assigned however. What is the correct way to go about passing an array from C to Ada?

Thanks!

Comment: `Integer` = `unsigned`? Funny.

Comment: I see nothing unsound with reinterpreting an integer as unsigned integer (or vice versa) on a programming language boundary. Just a bit surprising.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. Your first comment wasn't as helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do as you ask (I didn’t bother with `Buffer_Size`):

```
function C_Get_Buffer return System.Address;
pragma Import (C, C_Get_Buffer, "getBuffer");
Buffer_Address : constant System.Address := C_Get_Buffer;
Buffer : array (1 .. 10) of Interfaces.C.unsigned;
for Buffer'Address use Buffer_Address;
```

However, this might be appropriate as a shorter way of achieving the same thing:

```
Buffer : array (1 .. 10) of Interfaces.C.unsigned;
pragma Import (C, Buffer, "buffer");
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the first method suits my needs best. On a slightly different note, is it possible to achieve the same affect with access types, and System.Access_To_Address_Conversion? Say if you made Buffer_Address and access to Buffer?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can. Though it takes 6 lines to do the job instead of 5 (7 if you include the `with System.Address_To_Access_Conversions;`).