# Call C function returning Array from Ada

Tags: c, interface, ada

I have a C function which returns an array of integers. How can I import it in Ada and call it?

For my unsuccessful try, see below.

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *get_numbers ()
{
   static int numbers[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   return numbers;
}
```

**test.adb**

```
procedure Test is
   type Integer_Array is array (Integer range <>) of Interfaces.C.int;
   pragma Convention (C, Integer_Array);
   for Integer_Array'Component_Size use Interfaces.C.int'Size;

   function Get_Numbers return Integer_Array;
   pragma Import (C, Get_Numbers, "get_numbers");

   A : Integer_Array := Get_Numbers;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (A (1)'Img);
end Test;
```

EDIT:
I just found [Passing a C++ array to Ada95](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436417/passing-a-c-array-to-ada95) which worked, when I know its length.

But, is it possible to get a C array and iterate on it without knowing its length?

Comment: If you don't know the length, how will you know how to stop? If you have a sentinel, you should be able to cobble something together, but otherwise you're in the unenviable position of C not *knowing* what the length of the array as it's only syntactic sugar over a pointer to the object type. Do you have a sentinel?

Comment: "*I have a C function which returns an array of integers.*" No, you don't. C functions cannot return arrays. Your function returns a pointer to the array's first element.

Comment: To follow up on Keith's observation: When you use `Import` and `Convention` like this, the compiler will try to assume that what you're doing in Ada is the equivalent of what you're doing in C, and it will try to pass parameters in a way that makes things work.  But you're telling the Ada compiler that you have a C function that's returning an array; and since there's no such thing, heaven only knows what the Ada compiler will think you're trying to do.

Comment: In your case, since your C function returns a pointer, make the imported function in Ada also return an `access`, or better, a `Pointer` from an instantiation of `Interfaces.C.Pointers`.  That would be the equivalent to your C function.

Comment: @ajb, how do I handle this Interfaces.C.Pointer?

Comment: Should I better return a struct with the size and C pointer?

Comment: Did you look in the [reference manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12aarm/html/AA-TOC.html) for `Interfaces.C.Pointers`?  That should explain how to handle it.

Comment: Even using `Interfaces.C.Pointers`, you'll face exactly the same problem as if you were calling this function from C: when to stop the iteration? Normally a C function like this will pass back the length of the array concerned; nowadays (Ada2012) functions can have `out` parameters, so you could use `int *get_numbers(int *len)` rather than returning a `struct`.

Comment: I am using a struct at moment. Are out parameter still better than returning a struct, even with two or more out parameters?

Comment: I guess it’s easier to miss a field in a struct than it is to miss a parameter. But it’s pretty finely balanced.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use a data type to read any kind of memory.
Note that unconstrained array type expect to have bounds stored somewhere in memory.

Here is an example to use integer array type which seems to be the format of your data:

```
    with SYSTEM; use SYSTEM;

    function Get_Numbers return SYSTEM.Address;
    myReturnValue: SYSTEM.Address;
begin

    myReturnValue := Get_Numbers();
    declare
        arrayContent : Integer_Array (0 .. MAXIMAL_IMAGINABLE_ARRAY_SIZE);
        for arrayContent'Address use myReturnValue;
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (A (1)'Img);
    end;
```

Don't care about stack allocation, we only define a type for observability. But do not try to access the LAST element ;)